# Regular expression, finding a string contains but not starts with

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on parsing a text file, running through each line, and I'm having trouble figuring out the Regex. Part of this parsing involves changing occurances such as:

&Eacute; to &eacute;

I've tried the following regular expression, but it doesn't return anything:

```
/^(?!&)(&Eacute;)/
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When you design a regex, you can't work with "occurances such as". What is the specific pattern you're looking for? Will it always be an `&E`? Are you always changing it to `&e`?

Comment: Let's say i have the following line: H&Eacute;llo. I want to change that so it's a lowercase e. However, i dont want to change it if the line starts with that, as I'd rather leave it capitalized. I'm doing the replace using the gsub method of the String class.

Comment: what do you want to get?

Comment: Are you actually searching for the string `&Eacute;`, an html entity, or do you really want `É`, and were trying to make it show up in the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to match `&Eacute;` only if it's not at the start of the line?

Use

```
/(?<=.)&Eacute;/
```

(assuming Ruby 1.9 because 1.8 doesn't support lookbehind)

Rationale: `.` matches any character except newline. So if the lookbehind assertion matches, we're not at the start of the line.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ruby 1.9, you can use a lookbehind like this:

```
t.gsub! /(?<=.)&Eacute;/, '&eacute;'
```

In Ruby 1.8, you need to resort to something like this:

```
while t =~ /(.)&Eacute;/
    t.sub! /(.)&Eacute;/, "#{$1}&eacute;"
end
```

where t is your string to be modified.

Comment: `t.gsub! /(?!^)&Eacute;/, '&eacute;'` works fine in Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `&Eacute;` anywhere on the line, but not on the first position:

```
/^.+(&Eacute;)/
```

This matches e.g. `"abc&Eacute;def"`, but not `"&Eacute;"`

UPDATE: fixed errors pointed out by Tim

Comment: This doesn't work. It only matches if `&Eacute;` is in position 2 of the line.

Comment: Now it only matches if there is no other HTML entity on the same line before `&Eacute`...

Comment: @Tim Fixed it (hopefully), but your answer is better anyway.